# How should I disable some of my devise flash messages in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

How should I disable some of my devise flash messages in rails? I have customized all devise flash messages in config/locales/devise.en.yml file. I don't want all of them. Evenafter I  comment or delete some of those I find those appear in the UI. For example

```
en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      confirmed: "Your account was successfully confirmed."
      # send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions about how to confirm your account in a few minutes."
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists in our database, you will receive an email with instructions about how to confirm your account in a few minutes."
```

This I added in layouts/application.html.erb

```
      <% if notice %>
        <p class="alert alert-notice" style="color:#c09853;"><%= notice %></p-->
      <% end %>
      <% if alert %>
        <p class="alert alert-error" style="color:#b94a48;"><%= alert %></p>
      <% end %>
```

I have commented send_instruction. But when I run restart server, it still appears in UI. What is the possible solution? Thanks.

Comment: what if you set it to empty string?

Comment: but the empty bar appears at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your devise.en.yml file, specify each message as empty:

```
en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      confirmed: ''
      send_instructions: '' 
      send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists in our database, you will receive an email with instructions about how to confirm your account in a few minutes."
```

In your layout:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, value, :class => "flash #{key}" unless value.blank? %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: still the bar comes after adding the above. Result during inspect <%= puts value.inspect %>
<%= puts key.inspect %>
 ""                                                                  
"notice"

Comment: update your question, with code you are using in layout to display flash message

Comment: test notice and alert for blank.  <% if !notice.blank? %>  display only if it is not blank.